# Is there a symbol for the word "as"?

Tags: symbols

Much like & % #, or how "[that](http://www.mentalfloss.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/that.png)" used to have the thorn and T, does anyone know if at any point in the English language the word "as" had a symbol?

Answer (score 3):

A:B :: B:C = A is to B as B is to C

Thus :: = "as"

Comment: This is only recognizable within this formula though. (Doesn't save you any characters either.)

Answer (score 0):

There are [several shorthand systems](http://www.alysion.org/handy/althandwriting.htm) that encode *as* in the form of symbols. The Pitman system uses a [small circle](http://pitmanshorthand.homestead.com/BasicsofPitman.html) above the line. It looks something like this:

```
  o
_____
```

Answer (score -1):

There is none. Should you choose to pioneer the use of such a symbol, might I suggest ~, since it's not good for much else.  Looks like a worm in running away from something.

Comment: It's commonly used for 'approximately'

Comment: Plus "not" in logic, and a user's home directory in any Unix-like operating system. So not entirely useless, irrespective of any fleeing worm connotations.

Comment: I would suggest lower-case Omega...  Although it's used in some electronics-formulas for (if I remember correctly) "angle-speed" - 2*pi*f (2 times pi times frequency).  Why?  Because with a little fantasy, it looks like an a$$,..

Comment: It's also used for the 'difference' symbol (a ~ b = mod[a - b]), the 'is of the same magnitude as' symbol, and the 'varies as (ie is proportional to)' symbol in maths. Sometimes, if my memory is holding, merely as an abbreviation of  'relates/corresponds to'.